# ANTLR - number surrounded by single quotes

Tags: antlr4

I want ANTLR to recognize '10' (including the single quotes) but it just gives
me the error: missing ''' at '10'

Here is what I have for `Test.g4`:

```
grammar Test;

rules : number;
number : QUOTE NUM QUOTE;

NUM : [0-9]+;
QUOTE : '\'';
WS : [' '\t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Then the driver file looks like:

```
public class TestStuff{
    public static void main(String [] args){
    CharStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(" '10' ");
    TestLexer lexer = new TestLexer(input);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream ( lexer );
    TestParser parser = new TestParser(tokens);
    parser.rules();
    }
}
```

I've tried every variation I can think of and all I get is: `missing QUOTE at '10'`

I'm using version 4.1, if it matters.

Comment: Your example is incomplete, because if you just add a `grammar Sample;` clause to what you posted then it works fine.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't the whole file.  I just put in the parts that were relevant.  I'm using this on a string in java that looks like "stuff '10' blah blah blah" if that matters.  I don't think I need to escape single quotes in java.

Comment: Okay I've updated with more information.

Answer (score 4):

Your rule:

```
WS : [' '\t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

matches, and skips, the input `" '"` (space + quote).

Remove the quotes from that class:

```
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

and you should be okay.